# How to get Top Activity name of own App

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service, activity-manager

In `MainActivity` I want to know the current Top `Activity` opened inside App.

For pre-lollipop I used following

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
```

On other posts I found, I should use:

```
getAppTasks() and gettaskinfo
```

But I am not able to find any complete example demonstrating how to use the above. Any help is thankful. Regards.

Edit:
Current code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
      cn = am.getAppTasks().get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity;
}else{
      cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
}
```

am.getRunningTasks is deprecated in API 21. And am.getAppTasks#topActivity is available in API 23. So updated question is how to handle it for API 21 and 22.

Answer (score 6):

```
ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (mgr != null) {
  List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = mgr.getAppTasks();
  String className;
  if (tasks != null && !tasks.isEmpty()) {
    className = tasks.get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity.getClassName();
  }
}
```

Credits go to https://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-5-api-changes-getapptasks/

Comment: This code only works for API 23 and higher

Comment: Hi @Paritosh , i am getting topActivity as null here.